# Changing the Status Bar Color for specific ViewControllers using Swift in iOS8

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8, xcode6, statusbar

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
 return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

Using the above code in any ViewController to set the statusBar color to White for a specific viewcontroller ***doesnt work in iOS8 for me***. Any suggestions?  Using the UIApplication.sharedApplication method, the color changes after required changes in the Info.plist for the whole app.

```
// Change the colour of status bar from black to white
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

How can I just make changes to the status bar color for some required and ***specific ViewControllers***?

Comment: Here is the best solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76609795/3887987

Answer (score 366, accepted):

After reading all the suggestions, and trying out a few things, I could get this to work for specific viewcontrollers using the following steps :

**First Step:**

Open your info.plist and insert a new key named "*View controller-based status bar appearance*" to ***NO***

**Second Step (Just an explanation, no need to implement this):**

Normally we put the following code in the application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
method of the AppDelegate,

***Swift 2***

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

***Swift 3***

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

but that *affects the `statusBarStyle` of all the ViewControllers.*

**So, how to get this working for specific ViewControllers - Final Step:**

Open the viewcontroller file where you want to change the `statusBarStyle` and put the following code in `viewWillAppear()`,

***Swift 2***

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

***Swift 3***

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Also, implement the `viewWillDisappear()` method for that specific viewController and put the following lines of code,

***Swift 2***

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default

}
```

***Swift 3***

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
}
```

This step will first change the `statusBarStyle` for the specific viewcontroller and then change it back to `default` when the specific viewcontroller disappears. Not implementing the `viewWillDisappear()` will change the `statusBarStyle` permanently to the new defined value of `UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent`

Comment: Note that if you set `Status bar is initially hidden = YES` in info.plist file, "View controller-based status bar appearance = NO" will cause the status bar become hidden.

Comment: If you are changing back to `UIStatusBarStyle.Default` using `viewWillDisappear()`, you should be using `viewWillAppear()` to initialize it, rather than `viewDidLoad()`.... otherwise if you come back to that view without it having to re-load, you won't see the `StatusBarStyle` you are expecting.

Comment: Note you can use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle()` if you want to animate the statue bar's changes

Comment: **For Swift 3:** `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent`

Comment: It's still not clear how you change the color of the status bar

Comment: Guys, its deprecated from iOS 9

Comment: **for iOS 13 and up** add and set `NO` for `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key in Info.plist file, and than set **Status Bar Style** to **Light Content** in **General** tab from **project target settings.**

Answer (score 163):

*(As of October 25, 2021)*

**Swift 5**, **Swift 4.2**, **Swift 4**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    .lightContent
}
```

Comment: Make sure to call `super.viewWillAppear` if you're copy and pasting this code

Comment: Edited to included super.viewWillAppear(). Thanks @StephenSilber for the tip!

Comment: you have to override the preferredStatusStyle or it won't work. thanks for pointing that out. +1

Comment: Using `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` results in this compiler warning: Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Comment: In your application's Info.plist, set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES

Comment: no worky if set otherwise elsewhere in the code. Also not the right answer since the OP wants this per given view

Comment: @Alex, this is the way of doing per view. Please don't add #fakenews in the comments

Comment: how is this even a write answer? question is to change color of status bar not style...

Comment: @jayantrawat, welcome to Swift and Xcode. The way to change the "color" is to change the style. Apple provides 2 color options for status bars ... one is white, the other is black. Both are given their own respective "style" type

Comment: Does not work if your view controllers are embedded In a Root Navigation controller. If controller A is white, and push to controller B, this won't work, it will remain white.

Comment: If you present your view controller modally wrapped in navigation controller you need to set `modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` for navigation controller

Answer (score 52):

**Swift 4.2 solution with NavigationController**

**First Step:**

Open your info.plist and insert a new key named "*View controller-based status bar appearance*" or `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to *YES* to let each VC use their own status property.

**Second Step**

In each VC, override the *preferredStatusBarStyle* property like this :

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent //.default for black style
}
```

**Last step**

Override the *preferredStatusBarStyle* property in your custom NavigationController class :

```
class NavigationController : UINavigationController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {

    if let topVC = viewControllers.last {
        //return the status property of each VC, look at step 2
        return topVC.preferredStatusBarStyle  
    }

    return .default
}
```

Comment: This is only the way how to achieve expected result using Navigation Controller and your own controllers. Also you could do this way for prefersStatusBarHidden as I did for my project :)

Answer (score 32):

I followed this tutorial and it worked for me. However, I am not sure if there are any caveats.

https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift

- Open your info.plist and set
  `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `false`.
- In the first function in `AppDelegate.swift`, which contains `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, set the color you want.

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent`

- **Swift 3 Update** *

  UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

Comment: how is that specific to each view controller

Comment: Exactly, this is for the complete app, and that is not the question.

Comment: I'm using iOS 8 Swift and xCode 6.1.1 and just following these two steps doesn't work. You also need to add `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false` to the AppDelegate.swift didFinishLauchingWithOptions

Comment: This set it for the entire application. For specific view controllers, see the first answer. It worked for me.

Comment: Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Answer (score 21):

There's a billion answers here so I thought why not add another in the form of an **extension** (with help from @Cœur)

### Swift 3

#### Extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
    class var statusBarBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return (shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)?.backgroundColor
        } set {
            (shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)?.backgroundColor = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

#### Implementation:

```
UIApplication.statusBarBackgroundColor = .blue
```

Comment: Please note that this approach could be considered accessing a private API, and may mean your app will be rejected by Apple.

Comment: Or at least it's dependent on Apple's implementation details and may break without warning with changes in iOS.

Answer (score 20):

In your Info.plist you need to define View controller-based status bar appearance to any value.

If you define it YES then you should override preferredStatusBarStyle function in each view controller.

If you define it NO then you can set style in AppDelegate using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

Comment: `setStatusBarStyle` was deprecated in iOS 9.0

Comment: @Jeffrey_Neo Although that's true I cannot get the replacement to work. It would be useful to see your comment as an answer with working code.

Answer (score 15):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  true

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.respondsToSelector("setBackgroundColor:") {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: using `valueForKey("statusBar")` may not be compliant with Apple guidelines

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 3**

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
  statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

That's the solution for setting background color of the status bar for specific view controller.

Comment: UIView always responds to backgroundColor in Swift.

Answer (score 14):

(As of June 10, 2020)

**Swift 5**  (*Without editing `.Plist` file*)

If you are using `Storyboard`, go to the `NavigationController`, select the `navigationBar`, click on the `Attributes Inspector`, then change the `style`. if you need `light content` (*white status bar*)  set it anything except `default` lets say set style `black` And if you want `dark content`  (*black status bar*)  set it `default`.

The default (`UIBarStyleDefault`) results in the dark foreground `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` status bar. And `UIBarStyleBlack` will give a `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` status bar.

**Programatically**

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)

    nav.navigationBar.barStyle = .default //gives you dark Content status bar

    nav.navigationBar.barStyle = .black  //gives you light content status bar
```

**Without Navigation Bar** (*Edit `.Plist`*)

add `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` / `View controller-based status bar appearance` to your `info.plist`, and set value is `true`.

`Override` the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property in your Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**SWIFT 2**

I was able to successfully change the appearance of the status bar background by adding the following in my viewWillAppear:

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView

    if statusBar.respondsToSelector(Selector("setBackgroundColor:")) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

Implement `preferredStatusBarStyle` as you mentioned and call  `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in `ViewDidLoad` and 
also in Info.plist set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` (It's `YES` by default)

It is not clear why it is not  working.I need to check code.One other suggestion is 
go with working code in `viewDidLoad` `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent` and change this to default when you view get disappeared `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Just implementing the first part of the answer, worked for me. However, I did not add the UIViewcontrollerBasedStatusBarAppearance in the Info.plist. It still worked.

Answer (score 9):

Works for Navigation Based Application

```
    var addStatusBar = UIView()
    addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 20);
    addStatusBar.backgroundColor = global().UIColorFromRGB(0x65b4d9)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.view .addSubview(addStatusBar)
```

Comment: Where to add this specific code, just couldnt get this to work.

Comment: U can add it in App delegate file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 20) instead of hard coded 320 width?

Comment: Edited @TorstenOjaperv

Comment: How to do it with swift 3.0 ?

Comment: You can also add this to make it always appear on top even if you have things on other view controllers that would go over it. addStatusBar.layer.zPosition = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude

Comment: Status bar height change depend on iphone models.. use this UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height instead of 20 so code must be  addStatusBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.main.bounds.width, UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)

Answer (score 9):

In my situation,I use storyboard to organize my view controllers.I want to change all status bar style.

You can see in picture below.

[image]

`Stars` View Controller is a `CPBaseNavigationController`,and `CPBaseNavigationController` is subclass of `UINavigationController`.

I try doing the next setps:

1. In `AppDelegate.swift` func `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,add

   ```
   //change status bar color
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
   ```

   but no effect.
2. In StoryBoard,find the `Base Tab BarController`(picture on the above).select `Attributes Inspector`, change the `Sattus Bar` attribute to `Light Content`.so bad,no effect.

[image]

3. Last I get it.In my custom navigation controller `CPBaseNavigationController`,add func `preferredStatusBarStyle`

   ```
   override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .LightContent
   }
   ```

   It works well!

**Besides,`statusBarStyle` deprecated in 9.0,you can use `-[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]`.**

Answer (score 9):

Everything is much easier in Swift 3.0 Xcode 8

Using the code below in App Delegate file, after

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

insert this:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .black

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 230, green: 32, blue: 31, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: Red, green and blue values are in range from 0 to 1. You have to divide them by 255 or it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 3**

```
//
//  LoginController.swift
//  Swift 3
//
//  Created by The Crab on 17/01/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Paxi Labs. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 61/255, green: 91/255, blue: 151/255, alpha: 1)

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

for swift 3

.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Custom statubar
        UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions ... this only worked for me !! I dont know why :D

Comment: luck of the draw

Comment: Setter for 'isStatusBarHidden' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController prefersStatusBarHidden] ...

Answer (score 8):

Another really easy way to make this work is just to create an extension of the UINavigationController class.

Since overriding the `preferredStatusBarStyle:` method wont work **UNLESS** we do it inside of the UINavigationController class.

```
    extension UINavigationController {
        open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4** For specific ViewController without navigationViewController embedded just add this to your ViewController file.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: If we have a navigation controller embedded what do you do?

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 5 or xcode 11 and later set (**View controller-based status bar appearance**) key in info.plist as NO
Then go to project target and select general, Set **status bar style** to dark or light

Answer (score 5):

I had some trouble with this one. I didn't really feel good about globally changing the status bar color in view did appear and then changing it back on view did disappear like the accepted answer. Believe it or not you can get this working by overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` on your desired view controller. After much time this is what I did to get it working:

1. Change View controller-based status bar appearance in your `info.plist` to YES.
2. Now any full screen view controller can change the status bar style by overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle`.
3. I specify full screen because this will not work for (non-full screen) modal view controllers, not without setting `modal​Presentation​Captures​Status​Bar​Appearance` to Yes that is.
4. Also if you have embedded view controllers, like in a navigation controller for example, it will ask the top most view controller for status bar style. Overriding `child​View​Controller​For​Status​Bar​Style` and passing the embedded view controller is supposed to work but it didn't for me. So I just returned the embedded view controllers preferred status bar as the preferred status bar style. Something like this:

   ```
   override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if let topViewController = viewControllers.last {
            return topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }

        return .default
   }
   ```

Comment: This answer helped me! I found that for some reason my navigation controller (being presented modally) _wasn't_ implicitly asking the top-most view controller for its status bar style. So I had to subclass `UINavigationController` and override the `child​View​Controller​For​Status​Bar​Style` var in there, returning `self.topViewController`.

Answer (score 5):

### Custom color for the status bar (iOS11+, Swift4+)

If you are looking for a solution how to change the status bar to your custom color, this the working solution.

```swift
let statusBarView = UIView()
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
statusBarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    statusBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    statusBarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    statusBarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    statusBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)
])
statusBarView.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 4):

I had set specific color (in RGB format) using below code in `App Delegate` file:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
. . .

 UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

        let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
        if statusBar.respondsToSelector(Selector("setBackgroundColor:")) {
            statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.1, green: 0.27, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.0)
        }

. . .
}
```

You also need to add below key in `Info.plist` file :

**View controller-based status bar appearance** with boolean value set to **NO**

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: With Siwft 3.0, how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

I can suggest you a simpler way,

1. Just call [setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat) in viewDidLoad as Apple docs  says,

> Call this method if the view controller's status bar attributes, such as hidden/unhidden status or style, change. If you call this method within an animation block, the changes are animated along with the rest of the animation block.

2. Implement [preferredStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) returning your preferred type.

It worked for me in iOS 10.1.

**Objective C**

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**Swift**

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { 
    return .lightContent
}
```

I am surprised nobody pointed this out. Anyway enjoy :)

Answer (score 3):

What worked with me, in the Storyboard, go to the Navigation Controller, select the navigation bar, click on the Attributes Inspector, then change the style from default to black. That's it!

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 4 or 4.2**

You can add on your vc

> preferredStatusBarStyle

and set return value to

> .lightContent or .default

ex:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 Update

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 4.2**
Hey, I wanted to share a solution, that worked for me that I got from a great article on this ellusive subject by Graig Grummitt.

Step 1
As others have mentioned ADD below to your PLIST

```
View controller-based status bar appearance YES
```

Step 2 in the RootViewcontroller add below

```
var statusBarHidden: Bool = false {
        didSet(newValue) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return statusBarHidden
    }

    var vcStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .default {
        didSet(newValue) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
                self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
            }
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return vcStatusbarStyle
    }
```

When updating either property `statusBarHidden` or `vcStatusBarStyle` it will call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` and will update the status bar with the new values for either `prefersStatusBarHidden` or `preferredStatusBarStyle`. In my situation I had to update these properties for the container viewcontroller, that was the parent of the visable childviewcontroller. I did this using a simple delegate method.

```
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate {
    func updateStatusBarStyle(statBarStayle: UIStatusBarStyle)
    func toggleStatusBar(visable: Bool)
}
```

Ofcourse when instantiating the childViewController(Visible VC) don't forget to set the MainViewcontroller(Container VC) as its delegate. I sometimes do. :)

```
childViewController.delegate = self
```

Then in the childViewController I just called the delegate method when needed to update the status bar.

```
self.delegate?.updateStatusBarStyle(statBarStayle: .default)
```

As mentioned above Graig Grummitt goes into more detail about this solution and also working with UINavigationControllers as well. Link here: [The Mysterious Case of the Status Bar](https://medium.com/@craiggrummitt/the-mysterious-case-of-the-status-bar-d9059a327c97)

Answer (score 2):

There are two situation:

**1.show navigation bar**

1) add`1UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` / `View controller-based status bar appearance` to your `info.plist`, and set value is `true`.

2) Override the preferredStatusBarStyle property in your custom NavigationController class : (from @guillama)

```
class NavigationController : UINavigationController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {

    if let topVC = viewControllers.last {
        //return the status property of each VC, look at step 2
        return topVC.preferredStatusBarStyle  
    }
        return .default
    }
```

3) override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in your specific view controller:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

**2.hidden navigation bar**

1) ditto

2) don't need second step above, you should implement third step directly.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this way in **Swift 5, Swift 4.2**.

Add next values to Info.plist:

**UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = YES**

or

**UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance = NO** (to see changes)

**UIStatusBarHidden = NO**

**UIStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault** (or set to **UIStatusBarStyleLightContent** if you want to see *light status bar texts* on launching)

[image: Info.plist]

Then place code below to specific view controllers where you want to see light content (to see dark texts set preferredStatusBarStyle to **.darkContent**).

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .sunflowerYellow
    }
}
```

Comment: With this in viewDidLoad  "if let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .sunflowerYellow
    }"  the program crashing

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Supporting Files group(left side top - name of your project). Navigate to Info. Click on + somewhere between lists, like below bundle name. And add "View controller-based status bar appearence" and set it to NO.
Then open AppDelegate.swift and modify like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {

UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

return true
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: You read the question wrong. I asked about how to change the StatusBarStyle for specific viewcontrollers, not for the complete application.

Comment: Check my answer below @Anuj

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 10 you can create a class and put it before your viewController class, you can call this class in all view controller is needed a light content status bar...

```
class UIViewControllerWithLightStatusBar: UIViewController {
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
}
```

Now change your viewController class in:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewControllerWithLightStatusBar {
...
}
```

And that's all...

Answer (score 1):

Works for Navigation Based for particular view controller in swift4

```
   let app = UIApplication.shared
   let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = app.statusBarFrame.size.height

   let statusbarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: statusBarHeight))
   statusbarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
   view.addSubview(statusbarView)
```

Answer (score 1):

***WARNING***

---

Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
```

---

so my solution was as this:
making an extension from the navigation controller:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if let topViewController = presentedViewController{
            return topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }
        if let topViewController = viewControllers.last {
            return topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }

        return .default
    }
}
```

and if you have a viewController that will have another style than the style of the app , you can make this

```
var barStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    return barStyle
}
```

lets say that you app status style is `.default` and you want this screen to be `.lightContent`
so barStyle will take the `.lightContent` as its default value, this will change the status bar style to lightContent, and then make sure when `viewWillDisappear` change the barStyle again to the app status bar style which in our case is `.default` .

***this is works for me***

Answer (score 0):

*As of Oct 2020, Swift 5, Xcode 12*

If you want to set it to all view controllers in the app. and if your app has a navigation controller.

You can do it in the plist file as follow:
[image: plist file changes]

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 3**

In your `AppDelegate` file inside `func application` method

```
let statusBar: UIView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
statusBar.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score -3):

Swift 4.0 Please use this code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:" Appdelegate class

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)){ statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black }
```

iOS 13

```
 var statusBarView: UIView = UIView()
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let tag:UInt64 = 38482458385
            if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.viewWithTag(Int(tag)) {
                statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                statusBarView = statusBar
            } else {
                let statusBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
                statusBar.tag = Int(tag)
                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
                statusBarView = statusBar
            }
        } else {
            statusBarView = (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView)!
            if statusBarView.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)){
                statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -4):

if somebody wants to change the battery and text color of the status bar like the below image:

[image]

you can use the following code in the appdelegate class.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 46.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```