# iOS Custom Status Bar Background Color not displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am trying to fill the status bar background color to orange using the following

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

However, I get a white status bar that should be filled with orange instead from following this example: [Customize navigation bar appearance with swift](https://coderwall.com/p/dyqrfa/customize-navigation-bar-appearance-with-swift)

I am setting this up in the **AppDelegate.swift** file under **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method to apply it to the entire app.

I have edited my **info.plist** to the following: **`View controller-based status bar appearance => NO`**

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I'm not sure if it matters but the view is in a **UITabBarController**

Edit 2: This is happening in all the views actually, not just the **UITabBarController**.

Edit 3: Thanks *@Utsav* Parikh

I am adding a view now on top of the status bar and it for a brief moment while the app loads the status bar is orange but, once it finishes loading it gets pushed OFF the view and replaced with the generic white status bar. 
Why would this be happening?

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor=UIColor.orangeColor()
self.window!.rootViewController!.view.addSubview(view)
```

Edit for **Swift 3**:

with **UITabBarController**

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor = .orange
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

---

**Without embedded controllers**

I realize some people come here not only for the status bar, but actually the navigation bar, so I learned a few tricks along the way to do it without any embedded controllers:

Add this method in your **AppDelegate.swift** and call it in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func customizeAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
    let tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor
}
```

Comment: Visit to this link... it may helps  

 [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8

Comment: @AshokLondhe I have used that link prior to asking this question with no luck as well.

Comment: Change the status bar style under General -> Target -> Status Bar Style. See if that has any effect. Also try changing the appearance after app delegate has started up via a dispatch after and wait 2 seconds

Comment: @TheCodingArt I have just tried that and it is the same effect. I am able to get the LightContent for status bar style, but am not getting the orange background that should populate on top of it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I see that you aren't adding auto layout constraints. Could you please add constraints and ensure that you're view it added to the top of the top layout guide? That or bump your view's origin up to -20 on the Y axis.

Comment: I have added constraints from the navigation bar to the top layout guide and the results are still the same.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit for **Swift 3**:

With **UITabBarController**

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor = .orange
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

---

**Without embedded controllers**

I realize some people come here not only for the status bar, but actually the navigation bar, so I learned a few tricks along the way to do it without any embedded controllers:

Add this method in your **AppDelegate.swift** and call it in the **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func customizeAppearance() {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
    let tintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = tintColor
}
```

Thanks to *@Utsav* I added the following subview to my **UITabBarController** and this seems to be working now:

```
    let view = UIView(frame:
                    CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0)
                )
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

    self.view.addSubview(view)
```

The **UITabBarController** doesn't seem to play well in **AppDelegate**. If anyone has a better way let me know but, as of now this is the solution I have come around to.

Comment: If I add this code like directed, I get the error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'UIScreen'`, I'm using swift 3 and xcode 8. Any suggestions? I've started a bounty on this question, so if you can figure this one out you get 50 Rep.

Comment: @EmmetArries I have updated the original post without UITabBarController

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty new to Xcode and even less experienced with Swift. I tried the code of your second option where you specified and nothing changed. Here's what I need: I have a single view app that only has a UIWebView that takes up the whole screen. I just need something that can change the background and text color of the status bar. (Ideally the text would be white and the background 0.5% opacity, or transparency) Is that possible? If you need more details, let me know!

Comment: @EmmetArries try adding `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` to the `customizeAppearance()` method. without knowing anymore context it seems your whole UIWebView covers the whole screen which would make it not possible to change the status bar background. you would need to move the web view down 20pt since that's the height of the status bar

Comment: @Simon AHA! You where onto something! Your code didn't work out, but I got the background color I wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Add this code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** in AppDelegate

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor=UIColor.orangeColor()
self.window.rootViewController.view.addSubview(view)
```

Hope it helps you....!!!

Comment: "UIScreen does not have a member named bounds" is the error that I'm currently getting when I try this answer @Utsav

Comment: @Simon try UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width instead of UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width

Comment: I have just tried this and for a brief moment it adds the orange status bar while it is loading but, once it finishes loading it gets pushed OUT of the view and replaced with a white one?

Answer (score 6):

This is how I did it without adding a view in a VC with in a NavBarController

I wanted the color of the status bar to be the same as the VC view color so I just wrote:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Try it.

Answer (score 1):

I think your last line is reverting your changes, try this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that yields the same results. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

After what u did in `info.plist` to the following: `View controller-based status bar appearance` => NO.

Add this code in `AppDelegate.swift` file under `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = uicolorFromHex(0xffffff)
navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = uicolorFromHex(0x2E9AFE)

// change navigation item title color
navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

and u can select any hex code for ur choice of color..!! Enjoy..!!

Sorry, forgot to use hexcode you will be needing this also so add this code anywhere in your `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func uicolorFromHex(rgbValue:UInt32)->UIColor {

    let red = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0

    let green = CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0

    let blue = CGFloat(rgbValue & 0xFF)/256.0

    return UIColor(red:red, green:green, blue:blue, alpha:1.0)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however this does not solve my current problem. It looks similar to mine actually.

Comment: hey did u got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Simon's answer in swift 3

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor = .orange
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

There is one other way I know which uses private api. This has some benefits when orientation changes and keyboard is presented and view move up. I've used it and was lucky every time (app was released in the app store).

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

    guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }

    statusBar.backgroundColor = color
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "private api"? How would I set the color on the second option? And what do you mean by "lucky"? Does the app store not usually accept that way of doing things? Sorry I have so many questions, but I'm new to swift.

Comment: BTW I don't have a UITabBarController, so the first answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

In your AppDelegate.swift file paste the code bellow into your **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 20.0))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 130/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0) // Organge colour in RGB
self.window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(view)
```

This works fine for me!

Comment: Statusbar height should be dynamic, and colour needs to take `UIUserInterfaceStyle` into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

There is a main difference in `tintColor` and changing the background color of `UINavigationBar`. The best way in my opinion is apply a background image, made by 1 pixel square image of just one color.
Like that:

```
let tabbarAndNavBarBkg = UIImage(named: "nav_tab")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(tabbarAndNavBarBkg, forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

Or you can create a category on `UIColor` to return a `UIImage` given a `UIColor` instance, in objC:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithColor:(UIColor*) color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return colorImage;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this to no success. Should I apply a view on top instead? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you create an image with a solid color as written in the first line, does it work?

Comment: I created the image with a solid colour, it did not work. I edited my original post. I added a view and it seems that it is getting pushed up by the UITabBarController after it finishes loading?

Comment: You don't need to do nothing else than calling what I posted inside applicationDidFinishLaunching. If it doesn't work probably you are doing something wrong or the information given are not totally correct about the state of your project. Are you sure that the image is created after calling the image from colo method?

Comment: Yes, the image is being called but it applies only in the navigation bar area. The status bar is still left white. I would post an image if I could right now.

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar.appereance()` works for upcoming viewControllers, but not the currently displayed rootViewController. To achieve this I have added the following to my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = myColor

let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0].rootViewController as! UINavigationController
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = myColor
navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : myTextColor]
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false

navigationController.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem either. It is actually be segued to this view (UITabBarController) through an initial UIView.