# Custom Status Bar Color when using WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am trying to change the status bar color to match the color of a header in my app. The problem is, the app is just a WKWebView loading a web app inside it, so I need to set the status bar to match a header of a website.

I have been trying to figure this out, and have tried several things:

- Setting the tint/background color of the main view
- Setting the tint/background color of the WKWebView
- Setting the UINavigationBarStyle

I haven't been able to get it to work at all.

For reference, here is a picture of the main bar (inside the WKWebView, and the status bar. I need a way to make them the same color.

[image: Main header and status bar]

**EDIT:** I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341224/ios-custom-status-bar-background-color-not-displaying?rq=1), but it only works on the iPhone 8 and below. This solution doesn't work on the iPhone X or above because there is no way to modify it so that it always fits the height of the status bar. Not that I can find at least.

Comment: Do you know the color of status bar in advance? Like there will be always that color like in the picture?

Comment: Can we see how you've embedded the web view in code/interface builder?

Comment: @DionizB Yes, the color should always remain the same.

Comment: @KaneCheshire I hope [this](http://prntscr.com/kzmpxt) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Make following change in `AppDelegate.siwft` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .init(red: 65.0/255, green: 151.0/255, blue: 176.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: When I added the code, it threw the error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the line that deals with setting the font. Is it maybe the name of the font that was used?

Comment: @Koala King  I have updated the code to use it .if any issue let me know.

Comment: There was no change when I applied the code. I don't get the error, but the status bar still didn't change?