# Change color on the top of the Navigation Bar Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I change the color on the top of nav bar? Not really sure what that part is called, so apologies if the title of this question is therefore inaccurate

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Status Bar Color for specific ViewControllers using Swift in iOS8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the status bar.

---

You can change it between dark and light with a single line of code (Apple only would like you to do white or black, I believe).

In your `viewdidload()`:

For a black status bar: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default`

For a white status bar: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent`

---

You can also hide the status bar and put your own custom thing there, by putting this code snippet after your `viewdidload`:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
return true
}
```

I hope this helps you!