# Form Sheet iPhone Change Color at Top

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller

I have a view controller I am presenting as a form sheet. On iPads, it looks as it should. In iPhones, it presents in fullscreen which is fine but the top section that covers the status bar is white. It is like the form sheet is placed under the status bar. Is there a way to get the color to match the top of the form sheet?

Comment: Present a navigation controller as a form sheet . So status bar background color matches with Navigationbar bar tint color .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the color of status bar.
Have a look of below link for changing the color of status bar.

[Changing the Status Bar Color for specific ViewControllers using Swift in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8)