# How can I give textcolor in status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

Text color of the wordings in status bar cannot be changed. Status Bar background color is able to change. How can I change the text color in that?

Comment: May be this works for you.[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent // Light content, for use on dark backgrounds
```

or

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default // Dark content, for use on light backgrounds
```

Don't forget to edit "View controller-based status bar appearance" in info.plist and set it to NO.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I give textcolor in status bar?

You can't!

The only thing that you could do is to change the [UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle), which could be one of the two following options:

- `default`:

> A dark status bar, intended for use on light backgrounds.

[image]

- `lightContent`:

> A light status bar, intended for use on dark backgrounds.

[image]

So, if you are aiming to change the color of the elements in the status bar (black color in first screenshot and white color in second screenshot) to gray -for instance-, that would be not possible, you have to stick of one of the mentioned two options.

**How to change the status bar style?**

You could check the following answered question to implement it:

- [How to set Status Bar Style in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3).
- [Changing the Status Bar Color for specific ViewControllers using Swift in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26956728/changing-the-status-bar-color-for-specific-viewcontrollers-using-swift-in-ios8).