# StatusBar is white regardless of background color - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift5

My `statusBar` is white regardless of the background color.

I tried this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you give more context to your issue? Like, do you want to change the color of the `statusBar` for the whole app? Or only in some `ViewController`s? And if only in some controllers, are they embedded in a `NavigationController` or not? Providing more details makes it easier for people here to help you.

Comment: Why is this tagged `macOS`?

Comment: Use the debugger. Is your `preferredStatusBarStyle` override even being called?

Comment: I have a button that opens a screen. On this screen I want the navigationBar to be white and the battery and time indicators to be black.

Comment: I don't have just this screen. there are other screens before this one. Some are with navigationBar and some are not.

Comment: Then, this will guide you on how to achieve what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340663/11974184

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Create  a new swift file called PostingController.swift

```
class PostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Then change the line in the SceneDelegate.swift code file

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

from follow lines

```
window.rootViewController = PostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

The above answer is for SwiftUI

Comment: I don't have just this screen. there are other screens before this one.